# How can I make I make my GUI stay maximized ONLY if a certain window is open?

Tags: user-interface, autoit

I have a gui that helps me automate certain things, but only certain things in a specific program. I want my GUI to minimize itself when the program I use it for is not active, and be able to maximize itself when I activate that window again. Any help is appreciated. Also keep in mind, I'm pretty new to this! Thanks.

```basic
While 1
    Sleep(100)
If WinActive("My Program") Then
   WinSetState("My GUI", "", @SW_RESTORE)
   WinSetOnTop("My GUI","",1)
Else
   WinSetState("My GUI", "", @SW_MINIMIZE)
Endif
Switch $nMsg
Case $button1
   function()
Case $button2
   function()
EndSwitch
Wend
```

Comment: Please keep in mind you can edit your question if you notice a mistake or there's additional information you'd like to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your code would continuously set your GUI on top and minimize if your program is active.  This may help:

```
Global $ghActive
Global $ghMyProgram = WinGetHandle("My Program")
; if you're not already using a global handle for your gui
Global $ghMyGUI = WinGetHandle("My GUI")
While 1
    Sleep(100)
    $ghActive = WinGetHandle("[ACTIVE]")
    If $ghActive = $ghMyProgram Then
        WinSetState($ghMyGUI, "", @SW_RESTORE)
        WinSetOnTop($ghMyGUI, "", 1)
    ElseIf $ghActive <> $ghMyGUI And $ghActive <> $ghMyProgram Then
        WinSetOnTop($ghMyGUI, "", 0)
        WinSetState($ghMyGUI, "", @SW_MINIMIZE)
    EndIf
    Switch $nMsg
        Case $button1
            function()
        Case $button2
            function()
    EndSwitch
WEnd
```

Comment: I was able to get it fixed! Thanks for the response!

Comment: @HoustonLaunius If this answer solves your problem then you should click the checkmark next to the answer to mark the question as answered.

Comment: @mrt This answer wasn't what solved my problem, but since it appears like it would also do the trick, I'll do it.

Comment: @HoustonLaunius You can also post your own solution as an answer. ;-) This might then help people that stumble upon the same problem.

Comment: @mrt well, based on the couple of ^'s the above solution has, and how similar it is to what I ended up doing, I'm not going to do that. Thanks for your input though.